Moderator message view has relative link to chat
When viewing a message sent to a user, on the right side of the page is a container with text at the top What is a moderator message?.

At the end of that container there is a link at the end to chat but it doesn't appear to have a protocol so it is treated as a relative link. Notice in the screenshot below that when mousing over the link the browser shows that the URL from the href attribute is appended to the directory of the current route.

Can the href attribute be updated to an absolute URL?

I feel like someone reported this a while back, but maybe I'm misremembering...
